# Example of an axioms in G3Cp

Tags: predicate-logic, proof-theory

Would $$A,B,C \Longrightarrow C,A$$ be an axiom in G3Cp?
 I ask because B is not on both sides and I am not sure if that makes a difference or not?

Comment: You don't need to write $A,B,C=>C,A$; you can write $A,B,C\Longrightarrow C,A$. (I changed it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See :

- Sara Negri & Jan von Plato, [Structural Proof Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=Z--hngEACAAJ) (2001), page 49;

in the sequent calculus **G3cp** of classical propositional logic, the *logical axioms* are :

> > $P, \ \Gamma \Longrightarrow \Delta, \ P$

where $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ are finite multisets (they can be empty).

Thus, $A, B, C \Longrightarrow C, A$ is an *axiom*, where $\Gamma = \{ B, C \}$ and $\Delta = \{  C \}$.